# Passing variable into findelementbyxpath statement in selenium using vba

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Hi im trying to pass a variable into VBA code for running selenium webdriver, however the variable is being ignored everytime. if i type the string instead the code is picking it up

with string (this is working):

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//td[@class='day'][contains(text(),'25')]").Click
```

with variable (My_var variable being ignored, no error):

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//td[@class='day'][contains(text(),My_Var)]").Click
```

am i getting the syntax wrong?

Comment: you should share the relevant html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//td[@class='day'][contains(text(),'" & My_Var & "')]").Click
```

otherwise you're passing the literal text "MyVar" instead of the variable's value.